# How to access class function inside this.state.map()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use switchHandler function inside `this.state.persons.map()` but getting

> "Cannot read property 'switchHandler' of undefined" error

. However, if I'm using it outside the map function, it is accessible.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    persons: [
      { name: "Max", age: 28 },
      { name: "Manu", age: 27, child: "My hobbies : racing" },
      { name: "Ron", age: 26 }
    ]
  };

  switchHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      persons: [
        { name: "Maxii", age: 28 },
        { name: "Manu", age: 27, child: "My hobbies : swiming" },
        { name: "Ron", age: 26 }
      ]
    });
    //return "correct";
  };
  render() {
    //let obj = new App();
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.switchHandler}>Switch Name</button>
        {this.state.persons.map(function(data) {
          return (
            <div>
              <Person
                clickChild={this.switchHandler}
                name={data.name}
                age={data.age}
              >
                {data.child}
              </Person> // // Here I'm getting error for switchHandler

            </div>
          );
        })}
        <Person name="tag" age="34" clickChild={this.switchHandler}>
          just
        </Person> // Here switchHandler is working fine


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

## Error:

> App.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'switchHandler' of
>   undefined

Comment: You can try  :{ ()=>this.switchHandler}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code is inside map's callback function, (this)context will be referred as this of call back function.

Where at other place, its in render function, and (this)context is correctly referred to component this.

Put below line in render function

```
const self = this;
```

and then refer **self**.switchHandler where this.switchHandler not working  as below

```
clickChild={self.switchHandler}
```

Thanks

Comment: @Mrinal Welcome !! if you can vote the answer, would be great!!